# We need a closing tag: ASK YOUR ADVISOR

Tags: discussion

We need an option for closing questions that simply states: ASK YOUR ADVISOR.

The one that states that it involves individual institutions rules/customs is close. I know we're limited in closing options so we may not have this type of flexibility.

Comment: What problem would having that close reason really solve?

Comment: An academia equivalent of RTFM. I like the idea!

Answer (score 11):

If a question really is so situation-specific that it can only be answered by the OP's advisor, we already have a closing reason that applies:

> The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a certain person’s preferences, a given institution’s regulations, the exact contents of your work or your personal values. Thus only someone familiar can answer this question and it cannot be generalised to apply to others.

I don't really see why we need another close reason for this.

Comment: It's very broad. A lot of the issues we see could be simply resolved by better communication.

Comment: @RoboKaren: You can only fit so much information into a close reason, which is why I proposed [a FAQ to be linked there](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).